# Vertical scroll-bar of extjs4-multiselect is not displaying?

Tags: extjs

I'm using extjs 4.0.7 library. I have created UI as follows.
Landing page is a panel with border-layout.its north region have a panel with `id: 'filterPanel'`. This panel have a 'multiselect' component. Center region of landing page a tab panel, each panel having a grid.

Landing page has a listener, `afterrender`, on this listener I made `filterPanel` as collapsed by using `Ext.getCmp('filterPanel').collapse()`.

The issue is, system not showing vertical scroll-bar when I expand 'filterPanel'.

If I remove panel collapse code from listener, scroll-bar is displaying.

Our requirement is `filterPanel` should be collapsed while rendering the UI, that's why I tried to collapse filter panel on landing-page `afterrender` listener.

Is this approach correct?

Regards,
Ajil

Answer (score 0):

I got a work around for this issue. The steps which i followed is given below,

1. Add an expand listener for the panel here its 'filterPanel'
2. Remove all  element from multiselect component store.
3. Reload multiselect store.

I'm sure its not a good fix , but time being its work for me. 
Thank you all.